# AutoCompleteTextView - Show suggestions after selection

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, dropdown

I am using AutoCompleteTextView for address suggestions.

What I want to do is when user types in the address (f.e. "Ma"), suggestions are shown like "Mary, Madley, Ma...".

Then, when user selects one of the suggestions he immediately gets another suggestions containing whole address.

For example: He selected "Mary" and he gets suggestions like "Mary 123, Boston", "Mary 1566, New York", "Mary Jane 569, New York".

The problem is that suggestions are filled in adapter, but not shown. The drop down list doesn't show after selection.

So far my text watcher is assigned to AutoCompleteTextView responsible for suggestions:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if(etStreet.isPerformingCompletion())
            return;

        List<String> arrayValues = getValues();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrayValues);
        etUlica.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
};
```

I've tried calling showDropDown() on item click, text change and every other event, but it just won't show up. It only shows when user types on keyboard.

Comment: no idea maybe it work or may not... try to display suggestion again after selection done by user by writing autocompletetextview.showDropDown();

Comment: @MustanserIqbal I explained that I tried that at many places, but it still won't show.

Comment: i should work but maybe in this case it wont work.. coz i haven't tested

Comment: then u have to create your own custom auto complete text view.

Comment: I may be totally wrong as i don't know how your drop down works. Don't you need to notify after seeing the adapter?

Comment: dont know exact but setOnClickListener of AutoCompleteTextView you can try to set new adapter of your address using your name value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

write below code in your AutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener()

```
autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            autoComplete.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    autoComplete.showDropDown();
                }
            },100);
            autoComplete.setText(autoComplete.getText().toString());
            autoComplete.setSelection(autoComplete.getText().length());

        }
    });
```

And that's it, it will work like charm!!!

This will give you hint for your question, change according to your need and adapter data

Comment: Yes it seems to work, but why ? What operation is expected to complete within these 100ms ? And if it actually takes longer, what would happen ?

Comment: What I found out: Android will close the dropdown after onItemClick, so calling showDropdown there will not work. My recommendation is to use a onDismissListener to initialize the next suggestion there, instead using of tasks delayed with arbitrary durations.